# How to Uninstall Continuum

Tags: continuum

I'm trying to uninstall Continuum on my local machine and reinstall, but it keeps saying that it's doing an upgrade instead of an install.

I removed the /etc/continuum, /var/continuum, and /opt/continuum directories.

What am I missing when uninstalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuum looks to see if the CONTINUUM_HOME variable is set when running the installer to determine if it should install or upgrade. So in addition to removing the Continuum directories, you'll need to unset the CONTINUUM_HOME variable:

```
> unset $CONTINUUM_HOME
```

I'd also recommend removing the line that sets CONTINUUM_HOME in your user's .profile or .bash_profile. Otherwise, that line will appear twice once you re-install.

If you really want a clean install, remember to drop the MongoDB database as well.

For further information, try checking Continuum's official documentation on uninstalling: https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Continuum/Continuum_Installation_and_Maintenance/Continuum_Maintenance_and_Configuration/Uninstalling_Continuum